# Get citation relations from a given collection of papers

Tags: citations, bibliometrics

I have a pretty big collection of papers (as bibtex records) for which I'd like to add citation relations, i.e. a collection of cites(a,b) where a and b are two keys identifying the citing and cited paper respectively.

I want to avoid doing this annotation manually.
Is there some web service to extract this information automatically?